# Add Unique constraint in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

I have 5 fields in my table.

- Field1 value can be anything.
- Field2 value is selective one where user can select only one out of two option (Yes or No). If user selects no, then other fields are disabled (In the database other fields will be Null and field4 will be 0 since it is a yes or no). So in this case I need to check only whether the field1 and field2 are unique. If user selects Field2 as yes,then field3, field4 shows up.
- Field3 can be any value.
- Field4 is again a yes or no option. If user selects no, then field5 will not show up. In this case I need to check whether field1, field2, field3 and field4 are unique.
- If user selects yes for field4, field5 will show up and it can be any value. In this case I need to check whether all the fields from field1 to field5 are unique.

How to add the Unique constraint in SQL for the above case? I am using MySQL. If I can't add unique constraint to above condition, please suggest another method.

I tried following queries:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_channel_fields_idx 
ON channels (field1, field2, field3, field4);`
```

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_channel_fields_idx 
ON channels (field1, field2, 
CASE WHEN field2 = 'A' THEN field3 ELSE NULL END, 
CASE WHEN field2 = 'A' AND field3 = 'yes' THEN COALESCE(field4, '') ELSE NULL END, 
CASE WHEN field2 = 'B' THEN field3 ELSE NULL END, 
CASE WHEN field2 = 'B' AND field3 = 'yes' THEN COALESCE(field4, '') ELSE NULL END
) WHERE field2 IN ('A', 'B');`
```

But these are working only when all the fields are included.(In the above example I am considering only 4 fields,just for example sake).

Comment: You can not make field 2 and field 4 unique as it will be yes or no option. So it cant be unique

Comment: @FarhaMansuri Do you suggest any other method to achieve this?

Comment: I think you must add these constraints on the coding side, that if field 2 is selected he can add field 3 and 4. Just simple create the table where field 2 to field 5 value can be null and unique constraint for field 1, field3, field5. Handle rest all other things on the coding side

Comment: Although you may be able to use a combination of generated column with a unique index on the database side, to me this constraint belongs to the application logic, not to the database layer. In my opinion database constraints should be about basic data quality and integrity, not about complex business logic.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have such conditional constraints on database level. You essentially have two options: either enforce the constraints on code side or split your table into three tables that contain only necessary fields and put unique constraints there. In this case you wouldn't need field2 and field4 much, since their values would be implicitly set by having or not having related data. It would look like this (you didn't give any field definitions or PKs, so I'm filling the blanks with assumptions):

```
CREATE TABLE channels(
  id ... PRIMARY KEY, -- Or make field1 your PK if this fits your model?
  field1 ... UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE channels_field3(
  id ... PRIMARY KEY,
  channel_id ...,
  field3 ...,
  FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES channels(id),
  UNIQUE KEY(channel_id, field3)
);

CREATE TABLE channels_field5(
  channels_field3_id ...
  field5 ...,
  FOREIGN KEY (channels_field3_id) REFERENCES channels_field3(id),
  UNIQUE KEY(channels_field3_id, field5)
);
```

Note that the last table has a foreign key on `channels_field3` instead of `channels` - this will automatically enforce the condition that a channel can only have `field5` set if it has `field3` set.